# The WindowsDeveloperProgramforIOT file link leads to Page Not Found

Tags: intel-galileo, wdproj

I'm trying to set up my laptop to work with Galileo. I've followed the instructions on the "Setup your PC" page (http://ms-iot.github.io/content/SetupPC.htm) up to the point where it suggests I download the WindowsDeveloperProgramforIOT.msi file. However for me the link leads to the "Page Not Found: The content that you requested cannot be found or you do not have permission to view it" page. I made sure my account was linked to Microsoft Connect just in case this is the issue - it isn't.

Does anyone know an alternate download link for the file?

(Apologies if I'm missing something ridiculously obvious here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [this page](https://connect.microsoft.com/directory/accepting-bugs) and scroll to the row that has product "Windows Embedded Pre-Release Programs" and program "Windows Developer Program for IoT".

Click join, then follow through the forms and links until you get to the EULA. Agree to the license. The download link should now work instead of going to "Page not found" (if you are still logged into your Microsoft account).